# Conectar Java con Historian

Tags: java, odbc

mi consulta es referida a conectar Java con la base de datos Historian, se hace a través de un ODBC? Cual seria? o como se realiza? Desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que si es con un la ayuda de un OLE DB.

La misma página de Historian ofrece un ejemplo:

http://help.geautomation.com/Historian55/Subsystems/iHistODB/content/connecting_to_the_ole_db_provider.htm

**Connecting to the OLE DB Provider**

> To connect an OLE DB client to a Historian server on a local
>   connection (both software packages are on the same PC), all that is
>   required is the following line:

```
Provider=iHOLEDB.iHistorian.1
```

> To connect an OLE DB client to an Historian Server on a remote PC, the
>   following string should be used:

```
Provider=iHOLEDB.iHistorian.1;Persist Security Info=False;USER ID=[Username];Password=[Password];Data Source=[Target];Mode=Read
```

Comment: Hola Fernando, gracias por tu respuesta... tendras algun codigo de ejemplo? Soy nuevo en esto y no comprendo muy bien como se hace la conexion. La base esta en un servidor. Gracias.